# Small CLion project with C++ and SDL2 crashing with exit code 468

Tags: c++, sdl-2, clion

So I've been poking around CLion lately and wanted to set up an example project since I do game dev in my free time, but once I managed to have the CMake file work with SDL2, I ended up hitting the exit code 468 pretty much every time I attempted to run the program. Here is the code:

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "type_test.h"
#include "sdl_include.h"
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    Bidule bidule = Bidule(5, 'e');
    cout << bidule.get_truc() << endl;
    cout << bidule.get_machin() << endl;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)<0){
        cout << "Failed to initialise SDL. Error cause : " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("Titre", WIN_NOANCHOR, WIN_NOANCHOR, 160, 144, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (win == nullptr){
        cout << "Failed to create the window. Error cause : " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED| SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (renderer == nullptr){
        cout << "Failed to create a renderer for the window. Error cause : " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    int init_img = IMG_INIT_PNG;
    if (!(IMG_Init(init_img) & init_img)){
        cout << "Failed to initialise SDL_image. Error cause : " << IMG_GetError() << endl;
    }
    bool running = true;
    SDL_Event evt;

    while (running){
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&evt)) {
            if (evt.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

type_test.h :

```
#ifndef TEST_CLION_TYPE_TEST_H
#define TEST_CLION_TYPE_TEST_H

class Bidule{
    public:
        Bidule(short truc, char machin);
        short get_truc();
        char get_machin();
    private:
        short truc;
        char machin;
};

#endif //TEST_CLION_TYPE_TEST_H
```

type_test.cpp:

```
#include "type_test.h"

Bidule::Bidule(short truc, char machin){
    this->truc = truc;
    this->machin = machin;
}

short Bidule::get_truc(){
    return this->truc;
}

char Bidule::get_machin(){
    return this->machin;
}
```

sdl_include.h :

```
#ifndef TEST_CLION_SDL_INCLUDE_H
#define TEST_CLION_SDL_INCLUDE_H
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#define WIN_NOANCHOR SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED

#endif //TEST_CLION_SDL_INCLUDE_H
```

Does anyone know what I messed up or what this exit code means? (to be more precise, the Bidule class worked perfectly fine before I attempted to add SDL to the project)

I expected the program to run normally, since it compiled and linked just fine, but it doesn't even give me an error and just exits without running a single line of code...

Comment: What does the debugger show? Do you get a better error message if you double-click the exe in the explorer?

Comment: CLion's debugger is of no help here, I get the exact same code and the main function doesn't even seem to execute. I just tried running the executable from the explorer and nothing happens, the terminal window opens and closes immediately afterwards without even printing anything...

Comment: When I try to run the program from the terminal itself, nothing is printed at all, not even the exit code